# Spark Scala: Convert Map into Row object

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, row

I want to convert a Scala map into Row object (basically what Row(**dict) does in python I have to achieve it in Scala spark).

input : Map(com.project.name -> "A", com.project.age -> 23 )
output : Row(com.project.name="A", com.project.age = 23)

Please help.

Comment: @Dipali_Deshmukh Do you want it as dataframe or as Row? Also want are you trying to do here with this Row?

Comment: Row object , If we cannot do that then Can we convert it into dataframe and then from that dataframe we get Row object ? Row should return ultimately according to requirement,

Comment: you can check my answer below if that is helpful or near to what you were looking for

Comment: Can you check me answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Row.fromSeq`:

```
val m = Map("com.project.name" -> "A", "com.project.age" -> "23")
val row = Row.fromSeq(m.toSeq)
```

or alternatively `Row(m.toSeq:_*)`

both giving `[(com.project.name,A),(com.project.age,23)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert map into the dataframe as follows :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val input : Map[String,String] = Map("com.project.name" -> "A", "com.project.age" -> "23")
val df = input.tail
  .foldLeft(Seq(input.head._2).toDF(input.head._1))((acc,curr) => 
acc.withColumn(curr._1,lit(curr._2)))
```

Now if you want to get the Row from the Dataframe you can get as follows :

```
val row = df.first
```

And if you want to see the names of the column you can get that as follows :

```
val columns = df.columns
```

Comment: Hi I really appreciate your response , But I want output as -> Row(com.project.name="A", com.project.age = 23).

Comment: if you want what you are looking for. you can utilize Map for that purpose as Map is itself collection of key-value pairs. Map is similar to dictionary